# javascript first word selector

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors

This code changes the color of the first word found in that class. Works fine! But how can I change it so if there is only 1 word then don´t change that color?

Code:

```
$(function() {
    $(".widget-title").html(function(i, text) {
        return text.replace(/[a-zàâîïôèéêëèùûü]+/i, function(match) {
            return '<span class="red">' + match + '</span>';
    });
});
```

});

Thanks =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".widget-title").html(function(i, text) {
    return text.replace(/[a-zàâîïôèéêëèùûü]+/i, function(match) {
        if(match===text){return match}
        return '<span class="red">' + match + '</span>';
    });
});
```